# Parse & PubNub in Unity

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine, pubnub

I am having the problem that Parse and PubNub SDK cannot work in the same project.

The problem I have is both SDKs seems to have System.Threading in their DLL file. So I will get the following error

error CS0433: The imported type `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1' is defined multiple times

I use the latest Parse Unity SDK and PubNub example project here https://github.com/pubnub/c-sharp/tree/master/unity

Anyone has the same issue and how could you resolve it?

Comment: Linking to content off-site is generally not a good idea, as the link may go stale or be updated to make the question meaningless. Can you edit your question to explain what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse has their own "Task" class which clashes with the "Task" class in System.Threading.dll.

There are 2 ways to resolve the issue:

- You can either use the beta version of PubNub's Unity SDK from [here](https://github.com/pubnub/unity) (link to beta is in the read me). This version removes the dependency on System.Threading.dll.
- Or use `var saveTask = gameScore.SaveAsync ();` instead of: `Task saveTask = gameScore.SaveAsync ();` in the version you are using.

Another Example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Parse;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using PubNubMessaging.Core;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public void OnGUI (){
        SignUpNewUser ();
    }
    public void SignUpNewUser (){
        var returnTask = ParseUser.LogInAsync  ( login, password    ).ContinueWith (t => {
            return ParseUser.Query.FindAsync ();
        });
        returnTask.Unwrap();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried the beta version and it can be integrated into our project without problem. No clash between the SDKs anymore.